# flatlist is stuttering in arabic language

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I am using the Flatlist to display the products horizontally. When I am using the app in English mode RTL that time Flatlist is working fine, after switch the Arabic LTR the Flatlist stuttering, after drag this is come again in first where I start to the  drag the Flatlist items.

```
<ScrollView>
  <FlatList
    contentContainerStyle={styles.flatlist}
    data={list}
    keyExtractor={(item) => `post__${item.id}`}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    horizontal
    pagingEnabled={isPaging}
    onEndReached={false && this._nextPosts}
  />
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView
  horizontal
  style={{ flexDirection: I18nManager.isRTL ? 'row-reverse' : 'row' }}
>
  <FlatList
    contentContainerStyle={styles.flatlist}
    data={list}
    keyExtractor={(item) => `post__${item.id}`}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    horizontal
    pagingEnabled={isPaging}
    onEndReached={false && this._nextPosts}
  />
</ScrollView>
```

I found the solution need to add the

```
horizontal
style={{ flexDirection: I18nManager.isRTL ? 'row-reverse' : 'row' }}
```

line in the ScrollView.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11960#issuecomment-278918568